# Apex REST Data Source does not recognize all columns

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

my REST data source looks like this:

[REST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjmXQ.gif)

But apex can't recognize:

```
"categories": {
      "names": ["XYZ", "ABC"]
}
```

It looks like this

[DATA PROFILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt85r.png)

[DATA PROFILE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w6aT.png)

It looks like this.

Anyone had a problem with the parser?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APEX REST Data Sources cannot deal with nested arrays - as all APEX components work on flat, table-like data, REST Data Sources want to treat REST response data the same way.

In your case, the top-level information (which your screen shots indicate) is a single row, with multiple attributes (which then map to columns in APEX). Your "categories" attribute would then be a "nested table"; as it contains two values for the single row.

The same situation applies if the JSON contains an array at the top level; APEX treats then each array member as a "row" and the attributes of each member as "columns". However, if one of these attributes is -again- an array, we have the nested table again.

What you can do is to manually add the categories column to the Data Profile and to choose the "JSON Document" type. So, navigate to your REST Data Source and the Data Profile. Edit the data profile and add a new column.

- Column Type: **Data**
- Column Name: *{as you wish}*
- Selector:    `categories`
- Data Type:   **JSON Document**

When using the REST Source, e.g. in a report, the CATEGORIES column will contain `["XYZ","ABC"]`.

I hope this helps